# Perron's formula where the integrand of the contour is badly behaved at (and left of) zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am attempting to use [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) to recover the asymptotic form of a summatory function. Namely, it can be shown (is not difficult to prove) that for the [prime omega function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html), $\omega(n)$, its Dirichlet series for $\Re(s) > 1$ is given by 
$$D_{\omega}(s) := \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\omega(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s) P(s),$$ 
where $P(s) := \sum_{p} p^{-s},\ \Re(s) > 1$ is the [prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html). For example, this relation can be seen by showing that 
$$\prod_{p\mathrm{\ prime}} \left(1-\frac{u}{1-p^s}\right) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{u^{\omega(n)}}{n^s},$$ and then differentiating with respect to $u$. So, in principle, I should have by Perron's formula that 
$${\sum_{n \leq x}}^{\prime} \omega(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} D_{\omega}(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds,$$ 
for suitably large, finite $c > 1$. But now we arrive at a *BIG*, nay *HUGE*, complication, which is that due to the nature of its singularities, it is well-known that $P(s)$ cannot be analytically continued at or to the left of zero! I still would like to be able to approximate the contour integral on the right-hand-side of the previous equation.

**The next part of this is my attempt to enable this to happen within some not unreasonable added asymptotic error. Please help me to debug my working lemma to accomplish just this.**

There are fairly standard bounds on the [prime counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html), $\pi(x)$, for sufficiently large $x \geq 17$: 
$$\frac{x}{\log x} < \pi(x) < C \cdot \frac{x}{\log x}, C \approx 1.25506.$$ 
Now additionally, by a Mellin transform, we can write for all $\Re(s) > 1$ that 
$$P(s) = s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x^{s+1}} dx,$$ 
which is not too bad to evaluate and estimate if we plug in the previous upper and lower bounds for $\pi(x)$. Thus my question (I would love to make a little lemma out of this) is the following:

**Proposed Lemma:** Suppose that $$|R_1(s)| < |P(s)| < |R_2(s)|,$$ for all $\Re(s) > 1$, and moreover, the functions $R_1(s),R_2(s)$ can both be analytically continued to the entire complex plane, with the exception of at finitely many poles where we consider these functions to be undefined. Then for large enough (but finite) real $c > \sigma_P$, do I obtain that the contour integrals are bounded as follows:
$$\left\lvert \frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} R_1(s) \zeta(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds\right\rvert < {\sum_{n \leq x}}^{\prime} \omega(n) < \left\lvert \frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} R_2(s) \zeta(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds\right\rvert.$$ 
Are there any additional necessary conditions that need to be placed on the functions $R_1(s),R_2(s)$ to give truth to the previous inequalities?

*Thanks in advance. I really do have a good application in mind for this lemma.*

Comment: Perhaps this can be proved with an extension of the proof of Perron's formula given in Chapter 11 of Apostol's book?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you interested in an asymptotic bound for $\omega(n)$ in general, or only in a bound derived specifically via your proposed lemma?

Comment: The Mellin inversion of $\zeta(s) P(s)$ works exactly the same as for $P(s)$, see any proof of the PNT. We shift the contour on the left, not to a vertical line $c-i\infty,c+i\infty$ (with $c < 1$, not $c < 0$...) but to $\Re(s) = 1-A/(\ln 3+|\Im(s)|)$ (of course under the RH we can shift to $c-i\infty,c+i\infty, c = 1/2+\epsilon$). I don't see what you hope to get for $R_1,R_2$.  @StevenClark

Comment: My best explanation is that not all problem types are suitable for an approach via Mellin inversion and contour integrals. The sequence whose convolution was represented by the DGF product does not readily have nice properties using these methods. My solution (see preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.05842) to the problem type I was trying to model this way is somewhat different now. Basically, the realization is that there is an unsigned sequence whose distribution is known. And then there is signage from the Liouville lambda function -- more standard contour methods.

Comment: Maybe a plausible explanation in this case for why my initial contour formulation was so far off is that the DGF $P(s)\zeta(s)$ generates an *additive* function. So there is (as in the preprint reference) a nice Erdos-Kac type theorem for the unsigned summands. The signed weight terms, multiplicative they are, readily yield an appeal to classical contour methods -- though not that much is really well understood about $L(x)$...

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_T= \{ \sigma+it,t \in [-T,T], \sigma = 1-\frac{A}{\log(3+|t|)}\}$ where $A$ is found from the zero-free region detailed in the [proof of the PNT](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/main5.pdf).

$L(s) =\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^{-s}}{\log n}$ then $L(s)-\log(s-1),\log ((s-1) \zeta(s))$, $\log \zeta(s)-P(s)$ and $\zeta(s)P(s)-\zeta(s)L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ are analytic on some right plane containing $C_\infty$, thus

$$\sum_{n \le x}\omega(n) = \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} D_{\omega}(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{C_\infty} (D_{\omega}(s)-\zeta(s) L(s)) \frac{x^s}{s} ds + \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \zeta(s) L(s) \frac{x^s}{s} ds $$
$$ =  \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{C_T} (D_{\omega}(s)-\zeta(s) L(s)) \frac{x^s}{s} ds+O(\int_{1-\frac{A}{\log(3+|T|)}+iT}^{r+iT}|(D_{\omega}(s)-\zeta(s) L(s)) \frac{x^s}{s} ds|) \\+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty O(a_n \int_{d+iT}^{d+i \infty} \frac{(x/n)^s}{s}ds)+
 \sum_{n \le x} a_n$$

each term can be estimated to obtain 
$$\sum_{n \le x}\omega(n) =  \sum_{n \le x} a_n + O(\frac{x}{\log^k x}), \qquad\forall k$$

Comment: This is nice, and I appreciate the reference to the PNT proof, but your answer does not prove the lemma I had stated above. As I commented earlier, this example is *NOT* about obtaining asymptotic estimates for the summatory function of $\omega(n)$. Rather, it is asking for a *proof* of a more general statement that provided bounds on the Dirichlet series of a function (upper and lower, ideally), then the contour integral over the bounds actually *bounds the summatory function*! Please repeat where I have missed your proof of the lemma I requested help with in the post.

Comment: *Let me just summarize why this approach does not help in the special case:* You have defined $$a_n = \omega(n) - \sum_{\substack{d|n \\ d > 1}} \frac{1}{\log(d)},$$ and this implies that the summatory functions are $$A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \omega(n) - \sum_{d=2}^x \frac{1}{\log d} \left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor.$$ So using Abel summation to estimate the second sum, we arrive at the classically known result: $\omega(x) \sim \log\log x + O(x / \log x)$. I do not see how your proof is novel, or does any better than what we could have accomplished with elementary methods and divisor sums.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. $\omega(n) = \sum_{p | n} 1$. My answer has nothing specific to $\sum_{n \le x}\omega(n)$, it works exactly the same way to obtain the asymptotic of the summatory function of all Dirichlet series related to $\zeta(s)$. What do you want more ? Things like $\sum_{n \le x}\omega(n) = \sum_{d \le x} \frac{1}{\log d} \lfloor x/d \rfloor + O(x/\log^{10} x)$ imply the PNT you can't obtain it by elementary means.

Comment: Indeed. The question is to prove (a variant of) the lemma in my first post. The proof of the PNT is not even relevant here unless you are trying to give modernly trivial bounds for the *special case* example which the lemma can handle. I'm not asking for deeper bounds on the precise distribution of $\omega(n)$. That is another hard question. I would like to prove bounds on contour integrals defined over Dirichlet series. That is my objective with the post.

Comment: The "proposed Lemma" in your question doesn't make sense, things don't work like that, study the standard results on tauberian theorems that I tried to introduce in my answer....

Comment: Because I'm stubborn, and really have a good application for a lemma stating this sort of thing, I will nicely ask you to please provide me with an illuminating counter example which illustrates the concept.

Comment: Please see my recent comments on the original posting. The finalized idea was something else entirely for the application I was considering.

Comment: @reuns can you add in one or two more lines? i'm not following completely.  also can you tell me where i'm seeing things wrongly: to me your last equality reads $\sum \omega =\sum \omega -x\sum _{d\leq x}1/\log d+\mathcal O(x/\log x)$.

Comment: ah right no i think i get it.  (the last equality should be $a_n -\omega (n)$ right?)